# Cross-Domain XmlHTTPRequest in chinese after firefox update

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

My Firefox just did an update, and now all my `XMLHttpRequest` (that worked 10 minutes ago) answer in Chinese...

I can read this as responseText in firebug :

> "㰿硭氠癥牳楯渽∱⸰∠敮捯摩湧㴢畴昭ㄶ∿㸍਼㽸浬⵳瑹汥獨敥琠瑹灥㴧瑥硴⽸獬✠桲敦㴧⽯扩砯硳搧㼾ഊ㱯扪⁮慭攽≷慴捨㌢⁨牥昽≨瑴瀺⼯ㄲ㜮〮〮ㄺ㠰㠰⽯扩砯睡瑣桓敲癩捥⽷慴捨㌯∠楳㴢潢楸㩗慴捨∾ഊ†㱲敬瑩浥⁮慭攽≬敡獥∠桲敦㴢汥慳支∠睲楴慢汥㴢瑲略∠癡氽≐吵䴢⁭楮㴢偔こ∠⼾ഊ†㱩湴⁮慭攽≡摤䙲敱略湣礢⁨牥昽≡摤䙲敱略湣礯∠睲楴慢汥㴢瑲略∠癡氽∵〰∠浩渽∰∠⼾ഊ†㱯瀠湡浥㴢慤搢⁨牥昽≡摤⼢⁩渽≯扩砺坡瑣桉渢⁯畴㴢潢楸㩗慴捨併琢 㸍ਠ‼潰⁮慭攽≲敭潶攢⁨牥昽≲敭潶支∠楮㴢潢楸㩗慴捨䥮∠潵琽≯扩砺乩氢 㸍ਠ‼潰⁮慭攽≰潬汃桡湧敳∠桲敦㴢灯汬䍨慮来猯∠楮㴢潢楸㩎楬∠潵琽≯扩砺坡瑣桏畴∠⼾ഊ†㱯瀠湡浥㴢灯汬剥晲敳栢⁨牥昽≰潬汒敦牥獨⼢⁩渽≯扩砺乩氢⁯畴㴢潢楸㩗慴捨併琢 㸍ਠ‼潰⁮慭攽≤敬整攢⁨牥昽≤敬整支∠楮㴢潢楸㩎楬∠潵琽≯扩砺乩氢 㸍ਠ‼潰⁮慭攽≳瑡琢⁨牥昽≳瑡琯∠楮㴢潢楸㩎楬∠潵琽≯扩砺坡瑣桓瑡琢 㸍਼⽯扪"

This is fun, but I really would like to have my real answer back.

Do you know if I can change a setting or something?

An important thing to know, is that my ajax code is a crossdomain request. Is it possible that something changed in the http header encoding ?

Thanx a lot !

Comment: For information, my Firefox version is 19.0.

Comment: And in Wireshark evrything seems correct (I have my correct xml).

Comment: I found now anwser to this, but it seems to be a bug in Firefox 19 in cross-domain ajax calls.
I temporary fixed it with downloading the previous version of firefox : [firefox 18 download page](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/18.0.2/win32/)...

Comment: Solved : the problem was a bug in our code AND a regression in firefox 19. The xml was UTF-8 encoded but with a UTF-16 header. This was solved with changing the xml header. Note that this bug in our code caused no problem with all other browsers we tested or with older versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now gives precedence to the UTF-16 BOM over HTTP. This is not a regression but an intentional change. Better not use a UTF-16 BOM if the bytes after it aren't UTF-16!